# Continuous Search menu item not showing properly in android

Tags: android, search

menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="refresh" />
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

First time If I am open my app below one is my screen
[First time my screen was looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ0fC.jpg)

Next time onward my screen looks like this
[Next time on-wards My screen was looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpjHk.jpg)

Comment: Search bar is focused maybe

Comment: @MMG what focused may be

Comment: When you come back to this screen, search menu is focused?